# Cleaning black grime from bolts and screws after heavy metal workshop?

Tags: cleaning, stain, metals, garage, grease

What are good ways to clean up black stuff & staining from powder coated mild steel items & bolts/ screws, after DIY mods at a Lathe heavy metal workshop?

Anything anyone touches without washing their hands has black stains all over.

[image]

This is the only industrial workshop I have access to via a connection. I got some drilling & threading done. The workers hands are all black due to tons of lathe work being done there; mix of lubes, etc whatever applies to the lathing, drilling, threading, and other metal work of this sort. They never clean the parts as they are meant to go into industrial spaces. At most they do something called blackening before shipping it off.

No one gave me any inputs on how to clean these, so I do not know what chemical or solvent or liquid to use to wash these off the formerly clean surfaces. Surely I can't use soap & water? One fellow there said Collin spray (blue colored home use type of glass & multi purpose spray).

I will need to go there again for a few more and will come back with stained metal parts & bolts again.

I am in Asia, but US / UK Suggestions are welcome as long as I can source the product or translate that and its active chemical ingredient and find a local clone.

Comment: A shot in the dark; the threaded rods look like they are adjusted to some position to support a load. So they are turned while supporting a load.  In that case an extreme pressure lube may be used, commonly graphite or moly sulfide . Both are black materials that seem to get everywhere. The center rod in the bottom photo looks very much like it has a lube coating. If so, difficult to remove, wear gloves. What is  MS ?.

Comment: I guess mild steel.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - MS / SS isnt it common for you folks?  I basically got some drilling & threading done at this place as i know the folks who run it. Workers hands are all black due to tons of lathe work being done there; mix of lubes, etc whatever applies to the lathing, drilling, threading.. metal work of this sort. I do not know what chemical or solvent or liquid to use to wash these off the formerly clean surfaces. Surely I cant use soap & water, nor will it work well.

Comment: Sometimed machined parts are left deliberately greasy to protect them from corrosion - mild steel is not rustproof. You could wear protective gloves to load the parts into a box or plastic bag so you don't have to touch them. If I wanted to degrease a part, I would use an old brush and dish soap, rinse and and allow to dry thoroughly. For a quick partial clean-up, just wipe with a cotton rag.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I am aware that MS is not hence its PC unlike SS. These are not meant to be machine parts - these are daily home usage - but while in the shop they will get dirty. Is there not some non water "solution" or liquid that works better (given the metal work lubes are probably common/ usual) and does not expose the parts to water and moisture?

Comment: "Machined parts" - parts made by a machine. This is just shopping, not a hack, for example [degreaser](https://www.screwfix.com/c/auto-cleaning/degreaser/cat12630002).

Comment: @WeatherVane - Most people do not know what are the ways and solvents for such life hacks cleanups. Outside of soap and water for everyday items this is all strange terroritory.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to remove industrial lubricant is to:

- Remove as much excess from the surface as possible with absorbent 'wipes.' You may wish to wear protective coverings for your hands and face.
- Dissolve the remainder in a suitable detergent solution using a brush or with deionized water in an ultrasonic cleaner.
- Rinse the cleaned objects.
- Thoroughly dry them.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Vinegar. Leave submerged for 24 hours or, depending on grime, spray it on a cloth or towel to wipe the dirty surfaces off.
Then, rinse lightly, scrub with a light abrasive like baking soda then rinse again and make sure you lightly grease.  Preferably with some kind of oil, not WD-40.

Answer (score 0):

The Lifehack's way to remove industrial lubricant is to:

- Remove as much excess from the surface as possible with absorbent 'wipes.'
  You may wish to wear protective coverings for your hands and face.
- Soak the parts in WD-40®.
- Wipe "dry".

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Soaking in a container with coca cola for 24 hours is an excellent option.